# Natural log & L'Hopitals $x^x$

Tags: logarithms

I need someone to tell me the step I'm missing or doing incorrectly. The problem is:

> $$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ { x }^{ x } } $$

$1$. $\ln x^x$

$2$. $x\ln { x } $

$3$. This is the step I don't follow:
   $\frac { \ln { x }  }{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  }  $

I come up with: $\frac { \ln { x }  }{ x } $  at this point.

I'm missing this step in all the natural $\log$/l'hopitals problems I work. I picked the most simple for ease of explanation, if someone could be so kind?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Why do you come up with $\frac{\ln x}{x}$ ?

Comment: I guess I was taking the derivative of the x as thought it were lnx. It was the only thing that came close to what the solutions say to do.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ { x }^{ x }= } \lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ { e }^{ x\ln { x }  }= } \lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ { e }^{ \frac { \ln { x }  }{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  }  }\overset { L'h\quad rule }{ = }  } \lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ { e }^{ \frac { \frac { 1 }{ x }  }{ -\frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } }  }  }= } \lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ { e }^{ -x }=1 } $$

Comment: That is cool. I did not realize where 'e' fit into this. When x becomes 1/x, is that just a solid rule for x or whatever number comes before ln in this situation with 'e', that they are moved to the denominator in the form of 1/n, or is there some other methodology that leads to that step? I've not got a great background with logarithms or 'e', so this seems out of the blue to me. Thank you!

Comment: @Tonantzin,note that we know of from the property of log. that ${ a }^{ \ln { b }  }={ b }^{ \ln { a }  }$ in this case we have $a=e,b={ x }^{ x }$,hope it will help.you're welcome

Answer (score 2):

Even without L'Hospital, considering $$A=x^x \implies \log(A)=x \log(x)\implies \log(A)\to 0\implies A \to 1$$

Comment: Except that it  is not entirely obvious that $\lim_{x\to0+}x\log x=0$ when $\log x\to-\infty$. I'm sure you know the argument, but given that this more or less equivalent to the end claim...

Comment: I cannot do anything else than totally agreeing with you ! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your question to be about how $$x\ln x =\frac{\ln x}{\frac1x}$$

Here, they're using the rule that $\displaystyle x = \frac1{\frac1x}$ and that $\frac1b \cdot a = \frac ab$

That means that, with a bit more steps, we have $$x\cdot \ln x = \frac1{\frac1x}\cdot \ln x = \frac{\ln x}{\frac1x}$$

The reason this is useful, is that the limit now gives an indeterminate form that qualifies for L'Hopital.

Comment: That is precisely what I was having difficulty with :-) Thank you so much.